# Yii2 batch query for ActiveDataProvider

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a query used with kartik-v/export to export all results to excel that returns  a large amount of results and causes the server to run out of memory.

Here's an example query:

```
$query = Customer::find()->where('status'=>1);
$activeDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query'=>$query]) ;
return $activeDataProvider;
```

How do I properly turn this into a batch query? Or is there another way to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: Using data provider gives you paged result - are you running out of memory in this case? Or maybe the example you gave is so simplified that is not even close to the query you are using?

Comment: @bizley I should've been more clear. All results from activeDataProvider are exported to an excel file. Basically a user is able to export all their results.

Comment: See this demo http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo-dtl/large-files-link there is an option setting there for large file and memory problems.

Comment: @Bizley Disabling stream still results in the following error when generating a CSV:  PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Comment: You must either increase PHP memory limit or implement some other solution for this export.

Comment: @Bizley Thanks, decided to increase the memory limit. Was looking for a more optimal solution but I can deal with this as a temporary workaround!

Answer (score 1):

You could try  a batch query  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

> ```
>   // fetch 10 customers at a time
>   foreach (Customer::find()->batch(10) as $customers) {
>     // $customers is an array of 10 or fewer Customer objects
>  }
> ```

Comment: I need to use ActiveDataProvider since I'm exporting the results to csv using the kartik export plugin